# Extension of characters of an abelian group splits

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group and $\chi_1\ne\chi_2$ be two complex characters of $G$, then I'd like to know how to show that every short exact sequence $0\to\chi_1\to V\to\chi_2\to0$ splits.

I don't know why the condition $\chi_1\neq\chi_2$ is necessary here.

Thanks to the comments, this holds by Maschke's theorem. So I'd like to know what happens if $G$ is an infinite abelian group.

Comment: It's not necessary.  Are you familiar with Maschke's theorem?  (This is just a special case of Maschke's theorem.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maschke%27s_theorem has two proofs.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thanks for your comment. I just googled it. Maschke's theorem holds for finite groups. If $G$ is an infinite abelian group, do you know if such a sequence splits?

Comment: @Jean: it does not. For example there's a nontrivial extension of the trivial representation of $\mathbb{Z}$ by itself, given by $n \mapsto \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & n \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over a *finite* group, this is true much more generally: $G$ need not be abelian and $\chi_1$ and $\chi_2$ can be arbitrary representations.  More precisely, if $G$ is a finite group, then *any* short exact sequence of representations of $G$ over a field of characteristic not dividing $|G|$ splits, by [Maschke's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maschke%27s_theorem).

Without the finiteness hypothesis, the specific statement you ask about is still true, but the hypotheses that $G$ is abelian and $\chi_1$ and $\chi_2$ are distinct (irreducible) characters are necessary for it.  More generally, suppose $R$ is a commutative ring (e.g., the group algebra of an abelian group) and $M$ and $N$ are non-isomorphic simple $R$-modules.  Then any short exact sequence $$0\to M\to P\to N\to 0$$ splits.

To prove this, note that $M\cong R/I$ and $N\cong R/J$ for maximal ideals $I$ and $J$.  Since $M\not\cong N$, $I\neq J$, so $I+J=R$ by maximality.  Fix $i\in I$ and $j\in J$ such that $i+j=1$.

Now let $a$ be a generator of $N$.  To get a splitting of our short exact sequence, we need a lift of $a$ to an element $b\in P$ which is still annihilated by the ideal $J$, so that it gives a homomorphism $N\cong R/J\to P$.  Pick any lift $b_0\in P$ of $a$, and let $b=ib_0$.  Note that $b_0-b=(1-i)b_0=jb_0$ maps to $0$ in $N$ since $j\in J$, so $b$ is also a lift of $a$.  Now for any $r\in J$, note that $rb=i(rb_0)$ (here is where we use commutativity of $R$).  Since $r\in J$, $rb_0$ maps to $0$ in $N$ and so is in $M$, and thus is annihilated by $i$ since $i\in I$.  Thus $rb=0$, so $b$ is indeed annihilated by every element of $J$, as desired.

(So, to answer your question about the role of $\chi_1\neq\chi_2$, that is needed to conclude that $I+J$ is all of $R$ in this argument.)

For a more high-tech way to prove this result, you can use the fact that if $M$ and $N$ are modules over a commutative ring $R$ then $\operatorname{Ext}^*_R(M,N)$ gets an $R$-module structure from the action of $R$ on each of $M$ and $N$ and these $R$-module structures coincide.  So if $M$ is annihilated by an ideal $I$ and $N$ is annihilated by an ideal $J$, then $\operatorname{Ext}^*_R(M,N)$ is annihilated by both $I$ and $J$, and thus must be $0$ if $I+J=R$.

---

Let me finally give some counterexamples to show these hypotheses are necessary.  Let $V=\mathbb{C}^2$ and let $G$ be the group of invertible upper-triangular $2\times 2$ matrices acting on $V$.  Then $W=\mathbb{C}\times \{0\}$ is a subrepresentation of $V$ and there is a short exact sequence $$0\to W\to V\to V/W\to 0.$$  This sequence does not split, even though $W$ and $V/W$ are two non-isomorphic irreducible representations (even $1$-dimensional ones) of $G$.

If you require $G$ to be abelian, you can still get a similar counterexample except that you lose the condition that $W$ and $V/W$ are non-isomorphic.  In particular, let $H$ be the group of upper triangular $2\times 2$ matrices with $1$s in the diagonal (so in fact $H\cong\mathbb{C}$, identifying such a matrix with its top right entry).  Then $H$ is abelian, and the short exact sequence $$0\to W\to V\to V/W\to 0$$ still does not split over $H$.  This time, though, $W$ and $V/W$ are isomorphic (they are both the trivial representation of $H$).

You can get similar counterexamples with $G$ finite over a field of positive characteristic by taking $V=k^2$ for a finite field $k$ and considering groups of upper triangular matrices acting on $V$.